# What would be the most efficient way to implement this complicated dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, pdf, canvas, binary

Am working on a fun little python project, and I am stuck trying to adapt my switch statement into a Dictionary. I have visited multiple possible solutions but still I am unsure how best to implement this function.

I have Six Booleans, (bool1-bool6) that can obviously be T or F, and I need to test every possible combination of these booleans, so that I can tell my program where to draw the images.

There are 64 Possible combinations.

We can do this with 3 booleans to make it simple, There are 8 Possible combinations for 3 booleans.

If we imagine that 1=true and 0=false, then the possible combinations can be represented as such.

```
 000 (F,F,F) : drawstrings1()
 001 (F,F,T) : drawstrings2()
 010 (F,T,F) : drawstrings3()
 011 (F,T,T) : drawstrings4()
 100 (T,F,F) : drawstrings5()
 101 (T,F,T) : drawstrings6()
 110 (T,T,F) : drawstrings7()
 111 (T,T,T) : drawstrings8()
```

an if loop to represent this would be,

if (bool1==false and bool2==false and bool3==false)
      do stuff
elif (bool1==false and bool2==false and bool3==true)
     do stuff
elif (bool1==false and bool2==true and bool3==false)
     do stuff

and so on...

what I am trying to have run if these conditions are true, is a Canvas.drawstring on a pdf File. Essentially I have A program that makes invoices, and I have multiple services named Service 1-Service 6.

If All Services are being billed to client, then the layout would be 
Service 1
Service 2
Service 3
Service 4
Service 5
Service 6

But, If the Client has not been billed for service 3 or 5, Then I would want my invoice to be drawn more like this
Service 1
Service 2
Service 4
Service 6

Rather than this, which would happen without a dictionary.
Service 1
Service 2

Service 4

Service 6

Currently I have a Dictionary containing all 64 possible variants of 000000-111111, as well as corresponding commands. I.e.
{000000
 000001
 000010
 000011
 etc.
 111111

This all works fine for the time being, however I am worried about if I had to add more services to this program, how would I go about testing all the possible boolean sets?

I have seen some interesting Bit Shifting solutions, though the one suggested to me did not adapt well.

```
state = bool6 << 5
state = state ^ (bool5 << 4)
state = state ^ (bool4 << 3)
state = state ^ (bool3 << 2)
state = state ^ (bool2 << 1)
state = state ^ (bool1)
```

I have seen a good suggestion to use itertools, as in

```
 import itertools
 for i in itertools.product((0, 1,), repeat=3):
   stuff ...
```

However This option Still requires me to code individual function/methods for each key. with 10 possible services, that is 1024 possible combinations of 10 digit booleans.

I would love to hear any suggestions you guys may have.
This has been a tricky one for sure.

Comment: Anyone got any Ideas?

Comment: Would really like to see some more bit shifting solutions. this seems to be the most efficient way if it covers all possible combinations

Comment: With so many possible combinations, your whole approach may be ill-suited to the problem. Somehow the position about where to draw the images depends on these values, so I suggest trying to abstract the process of how that is being derived from the 6 booleans—and then write a single **function** that takes all the boolean values as input.

Comment: That is essentially what I have programmed right now @martineau. I have a function that sets booleans on or off depending on whether those services are valid, and 64 unique functions for all possible placements of those booleans. I was hoping that I was doing this the wrong way, and that someone may have a better way of doing something like this.

Comment: And the reason the position depends on the boolean value, is because if service 4 does not exist in my list of services, i would like to draw service 5 where service 4 should be located, rather than leaving a space for the service. python ReportLab makes you choose exact location to draw string

Comment: Are there 64 possible outcomes possible from that logic? If not, the dictionary may not need to be that big (and you could use the function does all the figuring to construct it). One reason I suggested using a function was it could be a different approach (or a hybrid one like I just described) might be better and scale-up more easily—there's a old saying that goes something like "If the only tool you know how to use is a hammer, all problems start looking like nails".

Comment: Yes, unfortunately given a True or False Scenario, base 2 dictates that for 6 digits, there are 64 possible combinations. 2 4 8 16 32 64 :(

Comment: Am now looking into using a generated table, but I think for positioning I will still need all cases programmed out, And I do agree, I feel like I must be using the wrong tool here, as many programs rearrange locations of things lol